# How to determine original layout folder to be used by application programmatically

Tags: android, android-screen-support, android-screen

How do we determine what layout folder does the application originally search for?

eg.

Application searches for layout-sw600dp but uses layout-xhdpi because sw600dp is not existing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The process for selecting the appropriate resources to use is outlined in the [Providing Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch) document in the Android Developer's guide.

> 1. Eliminate resource files that contradict the device configuration.
> 2. Pick the (next) highest-precedence qualifier in the list
> 3. Do any of the resource directories include this qualifier?
>
>    - If No, return to step 2 and look at the next qualifier.
>    - If Yes, continue to step 4.
> 4. Eliminate resource directories that do not include this qualifier.
> 5. Go back and repeat steps 2, 3, and 4 until only one directory remains.

In short, Android applications don't "look for" specific resource files; rather they pick the best matching resource file for a given device.

The table of qualifier precedence [can be found here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#table2).